# Head unit ignition switch wire has constant power

Tags: vw, audio, wiring, jetta, head-unit

I have an aftermarket head unit in my 2014 Jetta that I installed myself. After several times waking up to a dead battery when I was sure I didn't leave the radio on, I decided to kill all power to it when the ignition is off.

There are, of course, two power wires coming from the wiring harness. The yellow one is labelled "12v battery / constant", and the red one is labelled "12v ignition / switched". The head unit also has two wires for power, but I wired them both to the red wire anyway to make sure it didn't get any power with the car off.

After another dead battery and then verifying that the radio does indeed continue playing with the car off, I took a volt meter to it and confirmed: the yellow and red wires each give 12.5 volts regardless of if the car is on or off. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: "but I wired them both to the red wire " this was your mistake.

Comment: @Moab Why? The only downside I see to that is lost settings, but I don't care about that, and it doesn't even do that anyway because the red wire has constant power when it isn't supposed to.

Comment: If the red wire labeled "12v ignition / switched" provides power even when the ignition switch is off, then the red wire has been misconnected by someone so that it provides power all the time. It should not do this. You'll have to trace the red wire back forward to find out what's been done to it.

Comment: I think you should disconnect the unit completely and then test the wiring loom supply lines. It is unclear from the descriptions which wires you have shorted. *I wired them both to the red wire anyway to make sure it didn't get any power with the car off.* Wire it according to the manufacturer's spec.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I did. I wired it according to spec originally. I only changed it because I was having problems. The wire that was looking for constant power I also connected to the ignition wire. I don't care if the radio loses clock and settings or whatever every time the car is shutoff. It was when the radio even still had constant power that I used a voltmeter. I did check the wiring loom, and the terminals that go to the yellow and red wires in the wiring harness both have constant power. The wires coming from the car into those terminals are red with a yellow stripe. They look identical.

Comment: Really silly question but you did take the key out of the ignition when testing didn't you?  Some Volkswagens can detect a key inserted even if it isn't turned.

Comment: @SteveMatthews: I don't believe I did, but I do know the radio would still have power when the key was out. I ran a new wire from the cigarette lighter and used that instead of the red wire, and it did solve my problem. So while you bring up a good point that I hadn't considered, I'm still confident that somebody miswired the harness.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your wiring harness (the car side) is miswired, i.e. your switched power is actually constant power. You need to fix this so that the switched power terminal actually uses switched power.

Easiest thing to check is to remove the head unit (and as much of the surrounding plastics as practical) and peer into the wiring on the car side. From the factory you should have wires going into OEM terminals. A well-done head unit install uses an adapter harness that looks like this:

[image]

If you have wires changing colors, random electrical tape, homemade-looking connections that's your cue that someone was in there and hacked the wiring.

Next, look online for a wiring diagram for your vehicle for the head unit. These are generally widely available. Verify that the wires you are looking at in your vehicle match the colors that the wiring diagram says they are supposed to be.

If you go far enough into the harness you SHOULD find the proper OEM wire colors and proper functions.

If you can't figure this out, a hacky way out of the situation is to find some other switched power source. Most things on the car use switched power so this shouldn't be too difficult. Problems with this approach:

- Your radio will be on some random fuse.
- You could overload that fuse.
- You could have electrical interference from whatever else is on the circuit you'd be using.
- The fuse may be rated too high and your radio may burn out in a short.